# polkadotJS chain state system.account() include option false, how to rebuild with RPC?

Tags: polkadot-js, rpc

I'm trying to parse the whole storage from a node with the encoded partial key through RPC, it seems to be doable with polkadotJS see the picture in one call.

[image: system.account(AccountId32)]

The fastest approach that we currently have, which is not an unsafe RPC call, is `state.getKeys` or state.getKeysPaged and then `queryStorageAt`.

Is there a shorter way, like the representation in polkadotJS apps under chain state `system.account()` include option false, to query the whole storage? Or how is this representation done?

Answer (score 1):

To query the balance for a specific account as you said the method to be used is `getStorage` and to query all like the UI is doing is with `getKeys`.

I do recommend to read this blog from Shawn: [Querying Substrate Storage via RPC](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/querying-substrate-storage-via-rpc/) and use this [UI Substrate Utilities](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/) tool to create the hashes and decode the result.

The steps for your case would be:

```
util_crypto.xxhashAsHex("System", 128)

> "0x26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7"

util_crypto.xxhashAsHex("Account", 128)

> "0xb99d880ec681799c0cf30e8886371da9"
```

And you query with the combined storage key: `0x26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7b99d880ec681799c0cf30e8886371da9`

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getKeys", "params": ["0x26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7b99d880ec681799c0cf30e8886371da9"]}' http://localhost:9933
```

On the other hand using PolkadotJS you can query the whole storage as you are doing with the option false in your image from the PolkadotJS app using `entries()`. See an example below:

```
const wsProvider = new WsProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:9944');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
const allEntries = await api.query.system.account.entries();
allEntries.forEach(([{ args: [accountId] }, balance]) => {
    console.log(`${accountId}: Balance: ${JSON.stringify(balance.toHuman())}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Okay, and how is this resolved to the node regarding the RPC call(s) from PolkadotJS? Is it just wrapped in multiple RPC calls? Since I'm trying to find out how I can replicate this function via RPC over our C# Substrate API?

Comment: I have edit my answer to have how to recover with RPC calls, but the best way is how you mention with the state.getKeys